# How to make such wiggling effect in Android? ( see video )

Tags: android

Maybe someone know, how to make such wiggling effect, as in this video?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=gz2hgEdGuqQ#

When a bitmap responds to the users gestures by stretching/moving/pinching, etc. certain areas. Is there some library to do that or do you think it was all coded grass roots?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ApiDemos, one of samples in Android SDK.

Run it, open Graphics -> BitmapMesh.

Touch on image, see that it does similar thing that you want.

SDK function is [Canvas.drawBitmapMesh](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmapMesh%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

This "mesh" is array of vertices that change mapping of source bitmap to target canvas.

Your task then is to make these vertices to animate and live. Use some kind of simple physics (tension, animation) to make the effect.